# Bouncing Ball Collision

Tags: java, multithreading

I am writing a program that allows a user to left-click the panel and add a bouncing ball, and right-click to remove a ball. The balls bounce off of all walls with a constant velocity. I have all of this finished. The last part that I cannot figure out is handling the collisions with other bouncing balls. The same results as bouncing off of the walls should occur. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Here is the code for the movement of the ball so far...

```
@SuppressWarnings("AccessingNonPublicFieldOfAnotherObject")
private void processMovement(long interval)
{    
    /* Compute the distance moved in the interval. Decompose the distance
moved into x and y components, and determine the next position of the Ball
by those amounts. */

    float x = position.x + velocity.getDistanceX(interval);
    float y = position.y + velocity.getDistanceY(interval);
    position.setLocation(x, y);

    /* Collisions with the walls. If so, adjust the speed and direction for
       the next period. */

    /* Collision with the east or west (vertical) wall. */
    float wall;
    if( x <= (wall = 0.0F) ||
            x >= (wall = model.getDimension().width - SIZE) )
    {
        x = wall;
        velocity.reverseX();
    }

    /* Collision with the north or south (horizontal) wall. */
    if( y <= (wall = 0.0F) ||
            y >= (wall = model.getDimension().height - SIZE) )
    {
        y = wall;
        velocity.reverseY();
    }
    position.setLocation(x, y);
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why didn't it work? Is this a homework or coursework assignment?

Comment: You'll need a collection to store each ball object. You will then need to check them against each others positions to see if a collision occurred. A quradtree structure is an efficient solution for this

Answer (score 0):

When I wrote a program like this, I ended up creating a wall object, which had a start x/y and an end x/y.  Geometry was needed in order to determine the correct ricochet/bounce angle since walls could be at any orientation.  Essentially the direction of the ball changes by two times the difference in orientation between the wall and the ball's direction.  For example, if the ball is moving at 45* above the X-axis, and the wall is oriented at 90* above the X-axis (i.e. it's straight up and down), then the ball's new heading is its original heading plus two times the difference between its heading and the wall's direction, or in other words 45* + 2*(90*-45*), or in other words, 135*.  The problem is that it doesn't work if you consider the wall's orientation to be -90* (i.e. 90* below the X-axis, which is still straight up and down).  In that case you'd calculate the ball's new heading as -45* which is wrong.  It also matters if you hit the wall from the left or from the right.  Fun, right?  Lots of things to think about.

Balls collide when their centers are within (R1 + R2) distance of each other, where R1 is the radius of the first ball, and R2 is the radius of the second ball.

Essentially, what I did was I created a temporary (invisible) wall that was perpendicular with the vector from the center of one ball to the center of the other, and then I ordered the two balls to bounce off of this wall.  This gave the correct ricochet behavior.

I know you probably don't care about my "wall collision" stuff, but I think what I have described could give you something of an idea of the kind of geometry you're going to need to perform in order to solve this problem.

In short, bouncing balls off of each other *correctly* is difficult.  Consider removing/abandoning this functionality if it's not required and/or you're not willing to spend the effort.

You could also put together something less correct, but easier.  You could simply have balls move away from each other when they collide, but then you'd get "unnatural" looking ricochets.

I know it certainly doesn't solve your problem, but hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In Java (at least when using Bluej as the environment), the top left corner pixel is (0,0) and bottom left is (600,600)(depending on window size). Your logic is unfamiliar to me, but assuming your math is correct to have the balls reverse direction when hitting a wall you should have 4 if statements per ball. I know there are ways of getting away with 1 or 2 and my way is ugly and not very effecient, but a least it will isolate if the problem is your math of logic.

```
if (X<=0 || X>=600)
{
 velocity.reverseX();
}
if (Y<=0 || Y>=600)
{
velocity.reverseY();
}
```

I hope this helps :)